# Render lambda keyword as the greek symbol in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lambda

I want vscode to render `lambda` as `λ` in my editor. *I do not want it to **replace** the word with the symbol*, as that will just break my code since Python doesn't interpet λ as a keyword. It needs to purely be a rendering change, with the actual code still being `lambda`.

Are there any extensions that do this? Is it possible within the VSCode environment to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension [Prettify Symbols Mode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=siegebell.prettify-symbols-mode) allows you to do this. You'll have to edit your settings.json to specify this particular subsitution. To do this install the extension then go to the extension's settings page -> "Prettify Symbols Mode: Substitutions" -> edit in settings.json. Then add this:

```
"prettifySymbolsMode.substitutions": [
        {
            "language": "python",
            "substitutions": [
                {
                    "ugly": "lambda",
                    "pretty": "λ"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
```

to the file.

There are more complete options and details available on the extension's page, and [here](https://github.com/siegebell/vsc-prettify-symbols-mode/wiki/Python) is a more complete example of a Python config (with a lambda expression).